# Using Android apps with native code on Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

When porting my Android app to Blackberry 10/Playbook, I get the error:

> native-code: x86

This error has also been reported [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Eclipse-gt-BlackBerry-Tools-gt-VerifyAPK-gt-BlackBerry-Verifying/td-p/2020321) and [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/10K-Developer-Commitment/issue-releated-to-porting-andriod-app-to-blackberry-sdk-10/td-p/2089913).   The app uses OpenCV for Android as a library project, which contains native code, and I'm aware that Blackberry lists native code as an [unsupported feature](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_playbook_software_features.html).  Is there any way to get apps with native code to work on Blackberry, even for experimental purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you'll have to port it over to Blackberry's Native Platform.

http://developer.blackberry.com/develop/platform_choice/ndk.html

It looks like Blackberry put up a rough port on Github.

https://github.com/blackberry/OpenCV

I haven't used it so I can't comment on how well it works.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have to try building this when I have time.

Comment: To clarify, will this require rewriting my OpenCV code in C++?  Is there some way to use the Android wrapper?

Comment: Yes. If you are repackaging the apk file into a bar, then you may not be able to use the OpenCV features.